# Android Listview with multiple rows Like UperEats

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, radio-button

As you can see in screenshots i need to implement the same thing

The idea is that each product has options and each option has multiple
option items, the option can be single choice or multiple choice selection.

you can see the JSON below

```
   {"Id":1,"Name":"Special","Description":null,"HasOptions":true,"ProductItemImageModel":null,"ProductItemPriceModel":null,"Options":[{"OptionId":5,"OptionName":"Add Extra","Type":1,"OptionItems":[{"ItemOptionId":9,"ItemOptionName":"Green Pepper","ItemOptionPrice":2.5},{"ItemOptionId":10,"ItemOptionName":"Mushroom","ItemOptionPrice":2.5}]},{"OptionId":6,"OptionName":"DoughType","Type":2,"OptionItems":[{"ItemOptionId":6,"ItemOptionName":"Brown","ItemOptionPrice":2.5},{"ItemOptionId":7,"ItemOptionName":"Extra Thin","ItemOptionPrice":2.5},{"ItemOptionId":8,"ItemOptionName":"Regular","ItemOptionPrice":2.5}]}],"IsSucceeded":true,"Errors":null}
```

as you can see in options there is type,1 then its radio buttons options, 2 then its check box options.

I need the same as *UperEats*

**How can i implement this?**

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40VBJ.jpg)
[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/So8Ug.png)

[image]
[image]

Comment: no images are available.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/40VBJ.jpg

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/So8Ug.png

Answer (score 0):

For this JSON > UI conversion I would suggest to use either `PreferenceActivity`

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html

or `RecyclerView`

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html

it depends on what you namely want.

Answer (score 0):

It is better you should use `RecyclerView`. `RecyclerView.Adapter` class has `getItemViewType` method. You can decide which layout you inflate.

See [this.](http://getItemViewType)